# Break apart nested list into two (or more) lists if the nested list contains a vector of all NAs

Tags: r

I have a nested list (or list of lists) containing vectors of integers. I run this list through a custom function that randomly replaces the integer with NA. I would like to "break apart" the internal list into two lists if a vector contains all NAs

Its likely better with just showing you what I have and what I want instead of text explanation:

```
#Example of full list data
a<-list(1,3,c(0,2,0),c(0,0))
b<-list(1,6,c(0,3,2,0,1,0),c(0,0,0,1,0,0),1,2,c(0,0),2,c(0,0))
c<-list(1,0)
d<-list(1,0)
e<-list(1,4,c(2,0,0,0),c(4,1),c(1,0,0,0,0),0)
L.full<-list(a,b,c,d,e,)

#Example of list with random positions replaced with NA
f<-list(1,3,c(0,NA,0),c(0,0))
g<-list(1,6,c(0,3,NA,0,NA,0),c(0,NA,0,1,0,0),1,NA,c(0,0),2,c(0,0))
h<-list(1,NA)
i<-list(NA,0)
j<-list(1,NA,c(NA,0,0,0),c(NA,NA),c(1,0,0,NA,0),0)
L.miss<-list(f,g,h,i,j)

#To get what I want, I need to evaluate each list in the list-of-lists for vectors containing all NAs,
#and "break" into two lists (or more, if mulitple vectors in the list contain all NAs)

#In this example:
#"f" should remain complete since no vector in the list contains all NAs
#"g" should be "broken" since the 6th position only has one position and is NA (i.e. all NAs) and has subsequent positions in the list
    #"g" should be broken up such that:
    g.1<-list(1,6,c(0,3,NA,0,NA,0),c(0,NA,0,1,0,0),1)
    g.2<-list(2,c(0,0))
#"h" should remain complete since the NA is at the end and there are no subsequent positions in the list
#"i" should remain complete since the NA is at the beginning and there are no previous positions in the list
#"j" should be broken up since the 2nd and 4th positions contain all NA and have previous/subsequent positions in the list
    #"h" should be broken up such that:
    j.1<-1
    j.2<-c(NA,0,0,0)
    j.3<-list(c(1,0,0,NA,0),0)

#In this example, the original list of 5 lists would result in a list of 8 lists/individual vectors, such that:
L.want<-list(f,g.1,g.2,h,i,j.1,j.2,j.3)
```

I tried quite a few things but I am quite stuck. I thought I may be on to something when I realized a vector of all NAs is a logical, not numeric, so I started coding

```
#Checking each vector in the nested list for if it is logical
for(i in 1:length(L.miss)){
  for (j in 1:length(L.miss[[i]])){
    if(is.logical(L.miss[[i]][[j]])){
        ##I have no idea what to do here to break it apart##
    }    
  }
}
```

I appreciate any advice or guidance!

Comment: Apologies, that was an error - L.miss should be `L.miss<-list(f,g,h,i,j)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to do a nested loop with `lapply`, create a numeric index based on `all` NA elements, and `split`

```
L.split <- lapply(names(L.miss), function(nm) {
    split(L.miss[[nm]], cumsum(sapply(L.miss[[nm]], function(x) all(is.na(x)))))
   })
```

From this, if we need to remove the elements that have all `NA`s

```
L.split2 <- lapply(L.split, function(lstA) lapply(lstA,
          function(x) Filter(function(y) !all(is.na(y)), x)))
names(L.split2) <- names(L.miss)
```

#### data

```
names(L.miss) <- c('f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j')
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you! The only additional question is that the names (i.e., f, g, h...) are not important, they were only used here to demonstrate in the example and create the example list. In my actual data, I have 2000+ lists that don't have "names". When I run your first line of code without the `names(L.miss)`, I get an error `Error in L.miss[[nm]] : invalid subscript type 'list'` Any way around this? At any rate, thank you again for your very helpful advice!

Comment: @jpsmith If you don't have names, just change `lapply(names(L.miss)` to `lapply(seq_along(L.miss),`